# Guide to maintaining a Windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, windows

Are there any guides, howtos, books, etc about installing and maintaining a publicly-accessible Windows Server 2008 (with IIS and SQL server) for programmers (that want to deploy their own apps)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this will be a publicly accessible server you should look specifically at Microsofts Windows Server Operations guide and their server hardening guide which will give good guidance on a secure deployment - you'll find both in Technet.

Comment: I'm having some trouble finding them, can you post some links?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc163140.aspx

Comment: Or for 2008 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc514539.aspx

Comment: The guide starts with "This guide provides instructions and recommendations to help strengthen the security of computers running Windows Server® 2008 that are members of an Active Directory® domain.". This is going to be only a one server, won't be part of Active Directory, or should I create an active directory only for itself?

Answer (score 0):

There are the usual answers like Patching, Firewalls, Defense in Depth etc....

More specifically there is the [Windows Server 2003 Security Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8a2643c1-0685-4d89-b655-521ea6c7b4db&displaylang=en) that includes a lot of info on hardening a base win2k3 box.

There is also the [Windows Server 2003 Security Compliance Management Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc163140.aspx). Not a straight forward document, but a lot of good information.

(There are equivalent documents for other Windows versions)